# HTML5 Canvas not clipping correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, clipping

I'm wondering if the following code yields appropriate behavior.   I feel like the top left square should still be green.  that is, if I clip one area, ten restore, then paint in  a second area,  the canvas paints in BOTH areas.  Why?

https://jsfiddle.net/s6t8k3w3/

```
var my_canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = my_canvas.getContext("2d");

//Make Clipping Path 1
ctx.save();
ctx.rect(20, 20, 100, 100);
ctx.clip();

//Fill Background with Green
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,255,0,1)';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, my_canvas.width, my_canvas.height);
//Close Clipping Path 1
ctx.restore();

//Open Clipping Path 2
ctx.save();
ctx.rect(50, 50, 100, 100);
ctx.clip();

//Fill background with Blue
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,255,1)';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, my_canvas.width, my_canvas.height);

//Draw Line
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(500, 500);
ctx.stroke();

//CloseClipping Path 2
ctx.restore();
```

Comment: Use `ctx.beginPath` before each individual set of path commands or else subsequent `stroke/fill` will redraw everything since the last beginPath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not actually opening a second clipping path with that second `ctx.save()`; to do that, you need to call `ctx.beginPath()`

Comment: Thanks so much to both of you.  Clearly I have to understand this subject better!  obviously, this works!